# De-index plugin files

Tags: plugins, seo

Our client noticed that plugin files are searchable via google, and asked us to de-index them. What's the best way to de-index plugin files on a WordPress website? We're on an apache server.

I'm not sure if I've provided enough information but not sure what else is relevant, so please ask specific questions if you have them.

Comment: robots.txt...? This isn't a WP issue.

Comment: @vancoder hm, that was my first inclination. I would say this is a wordpress issue because plugins are specific to wordpress. You would be surprised how different wordpress development can be from other frameworks!

Comment: Actually I've not seen plugin files being indexed before. I wouldn't have thought this was possible in the normal scheme of things. Are you somehow linking to these files within your site? Have they been included on a sitemap?

Comment: whatever you do on your side to prevent future indexing, you need to look at googles search console/tools to fix it on the Google side